# xmlns precedence?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request xmlns:a="http://example.com/a1">
    <a:description xmlns:a="http://example.com/a2">foo bar</a:description>
</request>
```

In which namespace is `a:description`, in `http://example.com/a1` or in `http://example.com/a2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://example.com/a2`

Children override the parent.

The namespace declaration already affects the element it is declared on (otherwise you could not set the namespace on the first element).